# How could Leptoquarks explain Lepton Flavour universality (LFU) violation?

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-moment, beyond-the-standard-model, leptons

I recently read about the possibility of Leptoquarks and that this new particle could also explain a possible LFU violation.
Why would introducing a new particle explain LFU violation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a [leptoquark?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptoquark)

> Leptoquarks (LQs) are hypothetical particles that would interact with quarks and leptons. Leptoquarks are color-triplet bosons that carry both lepton and baryon numbers. Their other quantum numbers, like spin, (fractional) electric charge and weak isospin vary among theories. Leptoquarks are encountered in various extensions of the Standard Model,

In general extra elementary particles in a new model  modify the effect of higher loop corrections in the calculations of an interaction. The fact that leptoquarks carry lepton number means that higher order loop corrections can be different for decays that end up in leptons depending on the type of lepton and the mass of the leptoquark, thus affecting universality.